# How to Get Desire Time and Date Format in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to Get date-time Format like (30 April 1990) my date is store in sql server Database
in default Format mm/dd/yyyy.
how to do that?

```
tsddate.Text = orderReader["deliveryDate"] as DateTime = new DateTime(?,,????);
```

Comment: If you store the date in the DB as string, you are already doing something wrong.

Comment: no it's in timedate format

Comment: in your question, you said the data is stored in a specific format. A timedate column do not have a format (but you database tool may use a format when displaying results).

Comment: yes so how it can be possible to desplay like this (30 April 1990) to user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify custom datetime formats using the ToString overload.

like:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string formatted = now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

And in your situation it would be something like:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(orderReader["deliveryDate"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
tsddate.Text = date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

see all the formats you can use here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: still gives error
Error 1 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('System.DateTime' is a non-nullable value type) D:\Old Windows\Tailor Mang\Tailoring\frmcus.cs 277 41 Tailoring

Comment: That would be an issue with casting orderReader["deliveryDate"] to a DateTime object. you could use (orderReader["deliveryDate"].ToString() as DateTime) but note that if the cast is not valid it will throw an exception. you could also use DateTime.TryParse() to check if the conversion is valid

Comment: actully it save in datetime format in database 
with orderReader["deliveryDate"].ToString() it desplay like mm/dd/yyyy    00:00:00 by default

Comment: You can call ToString() with date format on DateTime objects. Therefore you must first convert te value stored in orderReader["deliveryDate"] to a dateTime object. I editted my answer convert the string to a datetime with the format you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

```
tsddate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy}",orderReader["deliveryDate"]);
```

Comment: give error
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.IFormatProvider' D:\Old Windows\Tailor Mang\Tailoring\frmcus.cs 277 54 Tailoring

Comment: you are right and mr middelpat also right so he replay me first let me check his answer as Solution...and for u i would say God Bliss u